# 'bootstrap_tags' is not a valid tag library

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, pinax

I'm using pinax-theme-bootstrap-account with django-user-accounts.

When I want to use pinax templates I get this error:

```
'bootstrap_tags' is not a valid tag library: Template library bootstrap_tags not found,tried        django.templatetags.bootstrap_tags,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.bootstrap_tags,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.bootstrap_tags,account.templatetags.bootstrap_tags
```

Here is pinax-theme for signup.html:

```
{% extends "site_base.html" %}

{% load url from future %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load bootstrap_tags %}
{% block head_title %}{% trans "Sign up" %}{% endblock %}   
{% block body %}
   <div class="row">
       <div class="span8">
           <form id="signup_form" 
                  method="post" 
                  action="{% url "account_signup" %}" 
                  autocapitalize="off" 
                  class="form-horizontal"{% if form.is_multipart %}     enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %}>
               <legend>{% trans "Sign up" %}</legend>
               <fieldset>
                   {% csrf_token %}
                   {{ form|as_bootstrap }}
                   {% if redirect_field_value %}
                       <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
                   {% endif %}
                   <div class="form-actions">
                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{% trans "Sign up" %}</button>
                   </div>
               </fieldset>
           </form>
       </div>
       <div class="span4">
           {% include "account/_signup_sidebar.html" %}
       </div>
   </div> {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This error is due to the `django_forms_bootstrap` Python package not being installed; therefore, the django.forms.bootstrap import is failing.

```
pip install django_forms_bootstrap
```

Then add `'django_forms_bootstrap'` to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

and then restart your website or runserver.

Answer (score 3):

**An update...**

if you upgrade it to bootstrap4, you will face this error:

***'bootstrap4' is not a registered tag library.***

To solve it for Bootstrap4: official website [link](https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap4/)

Or use the easy installation feature in Python:

```
pip install django-bootstrap4
```

Answer (score 3):

**Another update** for `django-bootstrap5`.

I spent quite some time with this error. There are two tricky parts about the fifth version.

For starters beware of what you add. There are two concurrent packages on PYPI that have very similar names. One is `django-bootstrap5` and the other is `django-bootstrap-v5`. The one you want is the former; `django-bootstrap5`.

Secondly you are likely to mess up the import, since it has to be different from `django-bootstrap5` (since python does not support `-` in package names). The correct import is simply `django_bootstrap5`. This seems obvious but a lot of tutorials online (including the one I followed) refer to imports like this `bootstrap5`, that might be legacy or something but it doesn't work.

**In summary**

```py
pip install django-bootstrap5
```

Install the correct package.

```html
{% load django_bootstrap5 %}
```

In your *base.html* equivalent include the package like so.

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [

 ...
    'django_bootstrap5',
 ...

]
```

In the `settings.py` of your project add the package to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

I hope this helps someone down the line!

Answer (score -1):

django-bootstrap4 installation solved it

Comment: This answer is just a duplicate with less information.