# pinax-theme-bootstrap can't load bootstrap

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, pinax

I am currently using (or at least attempting to use) django-user-accout with pinax-theme-bootstrap. However when I attempt to use any of the provided templates I get the expected 
`TemplateSyntaxError: 'bootstrap' is not a registered tag library`. 
This error is thrown by the following line`{% load bootstrap %}`.

I realize that this is happening because I am not providing the dependencies (bootstrap, JQuery, Font Awesome). How would I go about providing them?

P.S. The closest duplicate that I could find was the following: ['bootstrap_tags' is not a valid tag library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23181448/bootstrap-tags-is-not-a-valid-tag-library).

**Edit**: I did add bootstrap to my list of installed apps. I even download a copy of bootstrap and added a **init**.py to fool python into thinking it was a module (distress call). All to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py should be something like:

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'bootstrap3',
    'bootstrap',
    'bootstrap_toolkit',
     ....
 ]
```

Comment: Reed the documentation at https://github.com/pinax/pinax-theme-bootstrap

Comment: See the "Getting Started"

Comment: I skipped the useful: bootstrapform. Thank you for your help!